# Modify a method declared in the superclass with Javassist

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

I'm trying to modify a method with `CtMethod#insertBefore` that is declared in the superclass. However, it seems to not be possible with Javassist.

```
private class AbstractTestDataSource {
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return connection;
    }
}

private class TestDataSource extends AbstractTestDataSource implements DataSource { 
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        return connection;
    }
    // other methods omitted
}
```

This is my `ClassFileTransformer`

```
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
                                  ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer)
        throws Exception {
    if (!className.equals("org/example/TestDataSource")) {
        return classfileBuffer;
    }
    final CtClass ctClass = createCtClass(loader, classfileBuffer);
    for (CtMethod method : ctClass.getMethods()) {
        if (method.getName().equals("getConnection")) {
            System.out.print(method.getName());
            System.out.println(method.getSignature());
            method.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"foo\");");
        }
    }
    return ctClass.toBytecode();
}
```

When I'm calling the `getConnection(String, String)` method, `foo` is printed to the console, but if I call the `getConnection()` method that is declared in `AbstractTestDataSource` nothing happens. 
What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I can confirm that both methods are instrumented because this is what is printed to the console:

```
getConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/Connection;
getConnection()Ljava/sql/Connection;
```

Comment: You've determined that insertBefore is called twice but you haven't checked what it's actually being called on. Try printing both the method name and descriptor. Better yet, see if you can get the actual classfile for the target class and disassemble it.

Comment: Ok, I think I know where the problem is. The superclass is not modified, because in the transform method, I can only transform the one class that is currently loaded. I think my options now are either to retransform the superclass or to dynamically overwrite the superclass method. Trying out the latter option now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to check whether the getConnection method is declared in a class other than the current one.

```
if (!ctClass.equals(method.getDeclaringClass())) {
    method = overrideMethod(ctClass, method);
}
```

If so, I create (and thus override) the getConnection method and delegate to the superclass.

```
private CtMethod overrideMethod(CtClass ctClass, CtMethod getConnectionMethodOfSuperclass)
        throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {
    final CtMethod m = CtNewMethod.delegator(getConnectionMethodOfSuperclass, ctClass);
    ctClass.addMethod(m);
    return m;
}
```

It doesn't feel like the ideal solution, but it is working fine.

Comment: I still don't see how your original code wasn't working. According to the [Javassist documentation](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html), you were modifying the super class's method. 
"Note that if a method is inherited from a super class, then the same CtMethod object that represents the inherited method represents the method declared in that super class. A CtMethod object corresponds to every method declaration."

Comment: Maybe whoever is in charge of the project would have insight into it (maybe it's a bug). I see this Jira page for it: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST

Comment: The problem is that I use javassist inside a `-javaagent` to modify classes at class load time. A javaagent can be seen as a Filter that is executed whenever a class is loaded. The relevant method is `public byte[] transform(..)` in `ClassFileTransformer`. Inside that method you can modify the `byte[]` of the currently loaded class (and only that class) by returning a modified `byte[]`. That's why any modifications to other classes (even the superclass) are not applied.

Answer (score 0):

You are not overriding the method getConnection() in the super class, that method has this method signature:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
```

In your child class you'll have to override this method with the same method signature, otherwise you are just creating a new method in the child class

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to modify both `getConnection()` and `getConnection(String, String)`, however it only seems to be possible to modify the methods declared in the child class and not the superclass.